# How to return the coordinates of the respective 3 vertexes of a DelaunayMesh's face?

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh, distance

I have a set of points `pts1` and a point `redPts` as below:-

```
pts1 = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[7]; RandomReal[1, {30, 2}]];
plot1 = DelaunayMesh[pts1]
redPts = {0.68, 0.75}
plot2a = ListPlot[pts1, AspectRatio -> 1];
plot2b = ListPlot[{redPts}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[plot2a, plot2b]
```

[image]
[image]

As you can see, `redPts` must lie inside a face of the Delaunay Mesh. I want to have the coordinates of the 3 vertexes of that face. What can I do?

One of my solutions is to check the distance of "all points v.s. red point" and then pick the 3 points with the smallest distance. But is that possible to make use of the `DelaunayMesh`?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** As noted by Henrik and Rahul the original answer is not the correct approach.  An alternative method that gives the correct polygon containing `redPt` is based on using `` Graphics`PolygonUtils`InPolygonQ ``:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[r_, p_] :=  Pick[#, Graphics`PolygonUtils`InPolygonQ[#, p] & /@ #] &@
   MeshPrimitives[r, 2];

Show[plot1, 
 Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point@redPt, Opacity[.5, Red],  f[plot1, redPt]}]]
```

[image]

To get the coordinates, use

```
f[plot1, redPt][[1, 1]]
```

> {{0.67033, 0.84245}, {0.620283, 0.648944}, {0.829905, 0.700287}}

Using Henrik's  example (`R`):

```
Show[R, Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point@redPt, Opacity[.5, Red],  f[R, redPt]}]]
```

[image]

**Original (incorrect) answer:**

```
Nearest[MeshCoordinates[plot1], redPts, 3]
```

Comment: This is incorrect; see Henrik Schumacher's answer.

Comment: Thank you @Rahul.

Comment: @HMC, the original  accepted version of this answer is incorrect as noted by Rahul and Henrik. I updated with a version that gives the correct answer. But you might reconsider your acceptance since the accepted version was incorrect.

Comment: Ah, finding another working solution is even better than deleting the post. =) I'd like to mention that your solution tests the point against each triangle and thus has complexity $O(F)$ (where $F$ is the number of faces). There are certainly cleverer ways to find the right triangle, e.g. [walks along edges](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.146.1390&rep=rep1&type=pdf) backed up by some BSP-based heuristic for the initial edge.

Comment: I expected ``Region`Mesh`MeshNearestCellIndex`` to do such a clever thing. While it is two orders of magnitude faster for Delaunay meshes with up to 80000 vertices, it starts getting super-linear growing runtime for larger meshes. (This could also be memory related and not related to the actual algorithm).

Comment: Henrik, this is just something to salvage the post:)  Btw, `MeshNearestCellIndex` is a great find.

Comment: @kglr Many thanks. That's really a good example that `Nearest` is not always correct. We just acted so fast to apply the same idea from another problem regarding points nearest to the vertical line to this problem regarding the point inside the triangle.

Answer (score 9):

Finding the correct triangle is a very delicate business. See for example:

```
pts1 = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[1]; RandomReal[1, {30, 2}]];
R = DelaunayMesh[pts1];
redPt = {0.68, 0.75};
idx = Nearest[MeshCoordinates[R] -> Automatic, redPt, 3];
r = Max@Nearest[MeshCoordinates[R] -> "Distance", redPt, 3];
i = Position[Through[(RegionMember /@ MeshPrimitives[R, 2])[redPt]], 
    True][[1, 1]];
Show[
 HighlightMesh[R, Join[Thread[{0, idx}], {{2, i}}]],
 Graphics[{
   Red, Point@redPt,
   Circle[redPt, r]
   }],
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image]

Fortunately, there seems to be a built-in but undocumented function for this task:

```
j = Region`Mesh`MeshNearestCellIndex[R, redPt];
MeshPrimitives[R, j]
Show[
 HighlightMesh[R, j],
 Graphics[{Red, Point[redPt]}]
 ]
```

> Polygon[{{0.925275, 0.578056}, {0.767697, 0.973336}, {0.544772, 
>      0.562659}}]

[image]

Comment: Wow, great example showing that `Nearest` is not always correct!