# Find surrounding vertices (simplexes) of a given point for DelaunayMesh

Tags: mesh

Generating a Delaunay triangulation of some random points:

```
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 2}];
dm = DelaunayMesh[pts];
HighlightMesh[dm, Style[0, Black]]
```

gives

[[image: Delaunay triangulation[1]]

For a point e.g.
    {0.3, 0.24}

How do I get the element this falls in, i.e. the three surrounding vertices/simplexes (in Python, in the `spicy.spatial.Delaunay` module, this would be the `find_simplex` command)?

Comment: Does this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/175474/45431) by @HenrikSchumacher satisfy you?

Comment: Ah! That is great, thanks. Why on earth there is a function for it that is not documented is beyond me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the property `"VertexVertexConnectivityRules"` to create an association and use it to find the indices of neighboring vertices:

```
ClearAll[neighboringPoints]
neighboringPoints = Association @ dm["VertexVertexConnectivityRules"];
HighlightMesh[dm, {Style[0, Black], 
  Style[{0, 1}, Directive[Green, PointSize[Large]]], 
  Style[{0, #} & /@ neighboringPoints[1], Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]}]
```

[image]

`neighboringPoints` takes an index(`i`) and returns the indices of neighbors of `pts[i]`:

```
neighboringPoints[5]
```

> {42, 32, 49, 8, 38}

You can use it to define a function that takes a list of coordinates and returns the list of neighboring coordinates:

```
neighboringCoords[p_] := p[[neighboringPoints @ (First@PositionIndex[p][#])]] &;
pts[[5]]
```

> {0.101634, -0.362799}

```
neighboringCoords[pts] @ {0.101634, -0.362799}
```

> {{-0.0193242, -0.316663}, {-0.041939, -0.584718}, {0.369882,  -0.553096}, {0.727515, -0.244872}, {0.202586, 0.17428}}

Similarly, you can use the properties `"VertexEdgeConnectivityRules"` and `"VertexFaceConnectivityRules"` to find the indices of neighboring edges and faces, respectively:

```
ClearAll[neighboringEdges, neighboringFaces]
neighboringEdges = Association@dm["VertexEdgeConnectivityRules"];
neighboringFaces = Association@dm["VertexFaceConnectivityRules"];


k = 38;
HighlightMesh[dm, {Style[0, Black], 
  Style[{0, k}, Directive[Green, PointSize[Large]]],
  Style[{0, #} & /@ neighboringPoints[k], Directive[Blue, PointSize[Large]]],
  Style[{2, #} & /@ neighboringFaces[k], Orange], 
  Style[{1, #} & /@ neighboringEdges[k], Directive[Red, Thick]]}]
```

[image]

We can also use a random point (`rp`) inside the convex hull of `pts` as input, find the vertex closest to `rp` and show its neighboring vertices, edges and faces:

```
nF = Nearest[pts -> "Index"];
SeedRandom[7777]
rp = RandomPoint[ConvexHullMesh @ pts];
k = First @ nF[rp];
HighlightMesh[dm, {Style[0, Black], 
  Style[{0, k}, Directive[Green, PointSize[Large]]],
  Style[{0, #} & /@ neighboringPoints[k], Directive[Blue, PointSize[Large]]],
  Style[{2, #} & /@ neighboringFaces[k], Orange], 
  Style[{1, #} & /@ neighboringEdges[k], Directive[Red, Thick]]}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Yellow, Point@rp}]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! I am surprised Mathematica doesn't have a built in function for this